# Extending classes in python

Tags: python, inheritance

Say, I have some `MainClass` which at some point in its methods has instantiation of an object of a `OtherClass` as an attribute of the `MainClass`.

```
mainobj = MainClass()
isinstance(mainobj.otherclassobj, OtherClass) == True
```

Now, I want to extend the `OtherClass`, and then use the `MainClass` with new extended class.

Do I have more convenient options, other than extending `MainClass` and redefining all of its methods which instantiate `self.otherclassobj` to do it from `ExtendedOtherClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the implementation of `MainClass` slightly, you don't need to inherit from it. Just have something like

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self, ..., otherclass=OtherClass):
        self.otherclassobj = otherclass()
        ...
    ...
```

Then `MainClass` will by default use `OtherClass`, but you can pass in `ExtendedOtherClass` as a keyword argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need `OtherClass` already, you can do something like

```
from other_class_module import ExtendedOtherClass as OtherClass
```

If you need both classes, or logic/method changed - you need to reimplement/extend `MainClass`.